# does facebook disabled to fire edge.create event at like button

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-like

I set up the facebook like button callback

But

1- it works only if i'm going to like external websites such as (google.com - yahoo.com ..etc) and it would fire up giving me the alert.

2- it won't working if i'm going to like facebook fan page such as (https://www.facebook.com/FAN_PAGE_NAME) it won't fire up.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.$j = $.noConflict(true);
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(response) {
        alert("Callback called");
    });
</script>

<!-- Embeds the like button -->
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
<fb:like href="https://www.facebook.com/E3lamion.Kazebon" send="false" layout="button_count" width="450" show_faces="false"></fb:like>
```

any help and dose facebook disabled it for fan pages or what the story behind his ?

~ thanks

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/457950334238629 - marked as resolved yesterday (but the comments say otherwise).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is correct. This is a known bug. It now works for everything but fan pages. You can follow the status here: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/457950334238629?browse=search_503d58108cb633632443461